# How to solve $a x \equiv 1 \pmod{b y}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Is there a **mathematical formula** (not include iteration nor recursive) which can solve $a x \equiv 1 \pmod{b y}$ ?

Note: $a$ and $b$ are certain integers, while $x$ and $y$ are arbitrary integer which are aimed to be found out.

Moreover, $ gcd (a,b) = 1$.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you assume $\gcd(a,b)=1$? Are you familiar with [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem)?

Comment: It is unclear whether you are looking for conditions that guarantee a solution exists, or a construction of one solution or of all solutions when one exists. Have you started by examining some simple cases where you can settle the issue?  Sharing your thoughts would help Readers understand where you have a difficulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then you can pick any $y\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\}$ such that $\gcd(a,y)=1$, thus $\gcd(a,by)=1$ and from [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem)
$$a^{\varphi(by)}\equiv 1 \pmod{by}$$
where $x=a^{\varphi(by)-1}$. For instance you can consider $y=k\cdot a +1$, for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

---

If $\gcd(a,b)=d>1$ (or $a=a_1d$, $b=b_1d$) and you assume *a solution $(x,y)$ exists*, i.e. $ax\equiv 1\pmod{by}$, which means $ax-1=k\cdot by$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, then
$$ax-k\cdot by=1 \Rightarrow d(a_1x-k\cdot b_1y)=1 \Rightarrow d \mid 1$$
which is a contradicton.

Comment: It seems that y is unnecessary here. can it change to 1?

Comment: @pah8J yes, of course. That will be a particular case of $k=0$ in $y=k\cdot a +1$